# Why won't the randomized values match the user values on my Python Battleship game?

Tags: python

I applied a -1 value on the end of the guess variables so that the values properly match up on the grid if the user inputs a value between 1 to 5 for the row and columns. Because the user won't be expecting to start the coordinates from 0 but at 1.

At first I assumed I fixed the issue, because the values matched the grid properly. But now even if the correct coordinates are entered, the program doesn't register it as correct, because the guess values will never match up with the randomized values that the program sets up before hand.

How do I work round this?

```
import random

Battleship_Board = []

for x in range(0,5):
  Battleship_Board.append(["O"] * 5)


def print_Battleship_Board(Battleship_Board):
  for row in Battleship_Board:
    print (" ".join(row))

print ("Let's play a game of Battleships!")
print_Battleship_Board(Battleship_Board)


def Random_Battleship_Board_Row(Battleship_Board):
  return random.randint(0, len(Battleship_Board)-1)

def Random_Battleship_Board_Column(Battleship_Board):
  return random.randint(0, len(Battleship_Board[0])-1)

Battleship_Board_Row = Random_Battleship_Board_Row(Battleship_Board)
Battleship_Board_Column = Random_Battleship_Board_Column(Battleship_Board)


print (Battleship_Board_Row) 
print (Battleship_Board_Column) 

for turn in range(5):
  Guess_Battleship_Board_Row = int(input("Guess the X coordinate:")) -1
  Guess_Battleship_Board_Column = int(input("Guess the Y coordinate:")) -1


  if Guess_Battleship_Board_Row == Battleship_Board_Row and Guess_Battleship_Board_Column == Battleship_Board_Column:
    print ("You sunk the battleship!")
    print ("My ship was here: [" + str(Battleship_Board_Row) + "][" + str(Battleship_Board_Column) + "]")
    break

  else:   
    if turn + 1 == 5:
        Battleship_Board[Guess_Battleship_Board_Row][Guess_Battleship_Board_Column] = "X"
        print_Battleship_Board(Battleship_Board)
        print ("Game Over")
        print ("My ship was here: [" + str(Battleship_Board_Row) + "][" + str(Battleship_Board_Column) + "]")

    if (Guess_Battleship_Board_Row < 0 or Guess_Battleship_Board_Row > 4) or (Guess_Battleship_Board_Column < 0 or Guess_Battleship_Board_Column > 4):
        print ("The inserted value is not on the grid.")
    elif(Battleship_Board[Guess_Battleship_Board_Row-1][Guess_Battleship_Board_Column-1] == "X"):
        print ("You already inserted this combination")
    else:
        print ("You missed my battleship")
        Battleship_Board[Guess_Battleship_Board_Row][Guess_Battleship_Board_Column] = "X"

    print ("Number of turns:", turn + 1,"out of 5")
    print_Battleship_Board(Battleship_Board)
```

Comment: It looks like you indentation got messed up. You should completely delete this code, paste it back in from the source then click the format as code

Comment: You can use `random.randrange(0, len(..))` instead of subtracting 1 and calling `randint`.

Comment: So like this `def Random_Battleship_Board_Row(Battleship_Board):
  return random.randrange(0, len(Battleship_Board))`

`def Random_Battleship_Board_Column(Battleship_Board):
  return random.randrange(0, len(Battleship_Board))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use 1-5 as your board coordinates, then you do not need to subtract 1 from the user input and all of your values will sync up the way you want.

```
def Random_Battleship_Board_Row(Battleship_Board):
    return random.randint(1, len(Battleship_Board))

def Random_Battleship_Board_Column(Battleship_Board):
    return random.randint(1, len(Battleship_Board[0]))
```

---

```
Guess_Battleship_Board_Row = int(input("Guess the X coordinate:"))
Guess_Battleship_Board_Column = int(input("Guess the Y coordinate:"))
```

---

Oh, you'll need to update your logic elsewhere to reflect the 1-5 grid values:

```
        if (Guess_Battleship_Board_Row < 1 or Guess_Battleship_Board_Row > 5) or (Guess_Battleship_Board_Column < 1 or Guess_Battleship_Board_Column > 5):
            print ("The inserted value is not on the grid.")
```

---

But you still need to subtract 1 when using the `guess` values as list indices. Note this code is not changed from your original:

```
        elif(Battleship_Board[Guess_Battleship_Board_Row-1][Guess_Battleship_Board_Column-1] == "X"):
            print ("You already inserted this combination")
```

But this code is:

```
        else:
            print ("You missed my battleship")
            Battleship_Board[Guess_Battleship_Board_Row-1][Guess_Battleship_Board_Column-1] = "X"
```

Comment: That messes up the grid display however, the value 1,1 now appears on the 2nd row and the 2nd column, because it's counting 0 as a row and column

Comment: But the user won't know to enter 0, they will start from 1, so row 0 and column need to be replaced as row 1 and column 1

Comment: Ah, sorry -- will take a look in a minute.

Comment: The way you presented it should work in theory, but it means the user will only be allowed to enter a value between 0 and 4, cause the grid rangers from row 0, row 1, row 2, row 3, row 4 then col 0, , col 1, col 2 ,col 3, col 4, The user won't know this they will automatically attempt to enter values 1 to 5 in the board and they'll be thrown off cause 1 will come off as 2, 3 will come of as 4,

Comment: Yeah, my mistake was removing your `-1` from the list indices -- and I see now that my changes do not actually make this much simpler or less confusing, so I removed that comment. In my defense, there were 3 boys running around having a pillow fight while I was reading this :p

Answer (score 0):

This appears to work for me. I got `4,1` as output of the row/col values, and when I entered `5,2` I got a message telling me I sank the battleship.

```
Let's play a game of Battleships!
O O O O O
O O O O O
O O O O O
O O O O O
O O O O O
4
1
Guess the X coordinate:4
Guess the Y coordinate:1
You missed my battleship
Number of turns: 1 out of 5
O O O O O
O O O O O
O O O O O
X O O O O
O O O O O
Guess the X coordinate:5
Guess the Y coordinate:2
You sunk the battleship!
My ship was here: [4][1]
```

Comment: That's exactly it, if you look at the grid, the X placement is row 4, column 1. But the program isn't matching the inputted values to the ranomized values. So in terms of the grid placement, that works fine. But in terms of the programming detecting it as the proper value it doesn't. I need the grid and value inputs to work together, so when the value is 4, 1, the user will input 4, 1 it will display exactly like on the grid in your answer and tell the user they got the correct value and that they sunk the battleship.

Comment: @JackRogers: In the above sequence, Austin first guessed (4,1), and so there is an "X" at row 4, column 1. That guess happened to correspond to board[3,0], so it was a wrong guess. So the "X" was placed and the next turn begins. That seems fine. Then, Austin guessed (5,2), which corresponds to board[4,1], which is the right guess, so the game ended.  Perhaps you don't like that "4 1" was printed initially, or that the "my ship was here: [4][1]" message dis not say "[5][2]"? That is just a matter of converting from internal coords to "user friendly" ones when you display things.

Comment: But the ship didnt log down for 4,1, it logged down for 5 2 even though the set coordinate is 4,1. I just want to construct it so the displayed coordinates match up with the users input and the display on the grid

Comment: You're subtracting 1 from the user's input. So when I enter 5, it subtracts 1 and gets 4. If you want the coordinates to match what the user input, you should add 1 to the randomly generated numbers, instead.